# How to plot vertical sets of data stored in a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with the structure of

```
columns = ['curve_number', 'x', 'y1', 'y2' ]
```

How can I plot (overlay) with `matplotlib` the curves of `x,y1` and `x,y2` for all `curve_number`?

The data structure is like

```
curve_number   x     y1    y2
1              .5     3     2
1              1      5     6
1              1.5    4     3
1              2      3     7
2              .5     5     8
2              1      3     7
2              1.5    8     3
2              2      9     1
3              .5     2     2
```

In fact, I have stored various sets of data vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure this is what you want, but you could simply try grouping by `curve_number`, then plotting each group in a loop.

The most complicated part of this is actually how you want to represent the individual curve numbers and `y1` and `y2` within each curve differently: in this example, I'm using a colormap to represent each individual curve (so you don't run out of colors if you have too many curves, it's on a gradient), and I've just changed the linestyle between the `y1` and `y2`. Actually a significant proportion of the code below is just for setting up the color gradient and creating a legend that accurately represents all this... The plotting itself is only done in the `for` loop

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# This import is just for the weird legend
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
# This import is for the colormaps:
from matplotlib import cm

fig, axes = plt.subplots()

# Setup colormap to have right number of colors (one per number of curves)
n = df['curve_number'].nunique()
colors = cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,n))

# Actual plotting
for i, (curve, data) in enumerate(df.groupby('curve_number')):
    plt.plot(data.x, data.y1, color = colors[i], linestyle='--', label='')
    plt.plot(data.x, data.y2, color = colors[i], label = curve)

# Regular legend (top right corner):
l1 = plt.legend(loc=1)
axes.add_artist(l1)

# Custom legend (bottom right corner):
custom_lines = [Line2D([0], [0], color='black', linestyle='--'),
                Line2D([0], [0], color='black')]    
l2 = plt.legend(custom_lines, ['y1', 'y2'], loc=4)
```

[image]

Comment: We don't know if this is what OP wants. But I liked the solution :) +1. You could simplify it slightly using the Curve number as index instead of creating an enumerate. Should work in this use-case.

Comment: Thinking about it more, I actually realized that OP would run out of colors quite quickly with my old method, so I changed it to plot the curves on a colormap.